# Why NullPointerException in Service after Application exit?

Tags: android

I am creating a webview based Android Application using Phonegap. To help the application, I have created a service that basically gets user's location from time to time and processes it and saves it.

This is what happens:

1. I run the application - I have `startService()` call in `onCreate()` of the MainActivity. There is no other activity in the application (until now).
2. The service runs, application runs. I can see all this in LogCat.
3. Now, when I press back key on application's first screen, application exits and as a result after few seconds I see stack trace in LogCat and message that application has stopped. The error is `NullPointerException`

I get the exception in method below at indicated line:

```
public void GetAvailableLocation(){
    vstore = new VariableStorage(); //Even when I assigned new object to vstore
    if(vstore.load("mobileNumber").equals("0")) // Exception occures here
        return;

    // Get all available providers
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getAllProviders();

    for(String provider: providers) {
        Location newLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if(isBetter(newLocation, locationListener.location) 
             && newLocation != null) {
             locationListener.location = newLocation;
         }
    }
}
```

The above method is first method called in `onCreate()` of service.

Please help me out on this.

Edit: here is the load method in vstore-

```
public String load(String key){

    Log.d(TAG, "Load key: "+key);
    try{

        if(!loaded){
            this.loadFromFile();
        }

        String result = null;

        if(key.equals("loggedIn"))
            result = Boolean.toString(loggedIn);
        else if(key.equals("mobileNumber"))
            result = Long.toString(mobileNumber);
        else if(key.equals("password"))
            result = password;
        else if(key.equals("gettingService"))
            result = Boolean.toString(gettingService);
        else if(key.equals("providingService"))
            result = Boolean.toString(providingService);
        else if(key.equals("gettingServiceID"))
            result = Integer.toString(gettingServiceID);
        else if(key.equals("providingServiceTo"))
            result = Long.toString(providingServiceTo);
        else if(key.equals("usersName"))
            result = usersName;
        else if(key.equals("currLatitude"))
            result = Double.toString(currLatitude);
        else if(key.equals("currLongitude"))
            result = Double.toString(currLongitude);
        else if(key.equals("prevLatitude"))
            result = Double.toString(prevLatitude);
        else if(key.equals("prevLongitude"))
            result = Double.toString(prevLongitude);
        else if(key.equals("lastLocationUpdateTime"))
            result = Integer.toString(lastLocationUpdateTime);
        else if(key.equals("publicKey"))
            result = publicKey;
        else if(key.equals("notification"))
            result = Integer.toString(notification);
        else if(key.equals("verifyMobileNumber"))
            result = Long.toString(verifyMobileNumber);

        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "VSLoad Error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: be sure that `vstore.load("mobileNumber")` returns something.

Comment: have you debug ? show your logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is a better way to write that condition:

```
if("0".equals(vstore.load("mobileNumber")))
```

"0" is always given. so if `load` returns null you will call `return;`
That is called null saved :)

Comment: @Shashank Jain: than the NPE occurs anywhere inside the load method. Debug it and show us the code for this method.

Comment: Okay, I will look into this and let you know. I just want to say one more thing. When I press back button and watch the Running Applications on Android, it shows zero processes and 1 service restarting. How can there be a service without a process?

Comment: becouse it only says one service is starting. you have 0 process becouse the starting fails as a result of the NPE. Post the load method. I am sure I can show you the problem.

Comment: actually your suggestion worked, i was editing in wrong method. But your could still help where is possibly exception occuring. I have posted the load method too in the question. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: you have to tell me where the exception occurs. just debug the code. set a breakpoint inside your load method and start application in debugmode. after that post the line where the exception is thrown or post the whole log cat.

Comment: I figured out that this is occuring because in loadFromFile() method I am using context that was stored in main activity which gets destroyed once i press back button. Now i need to figure out how to get context in non Android Class.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that vstore.load("mobileNumber") returns something

or write something like:

```
if(vstore.load("mobileNumber") == null || vstore.load("mobileNumber").equals("0")) 
    return;
```

Comment: I tried Stefan's suggestion, but yours is equivalant and it works. thanks for the help.